# Relative Root Url For Sub domain name

Tags: subdomains, wp-config, domain

I am really difficulties in using relative root url. I installed my wordpress site /root/mywordpress/tester1 folder and when I installed my wordpress sites with my subdomain like http://mywordpress.mydomain.com/tester1. It doesn't work and all images are broken.

Here is my use in wp-config.php file

```
    define('WP_HOME', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/tester1/');
    define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/tester1/');
    define('WP_CONTENT_URL', 'tester1/wp-content');
    define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] .'/tester1/');
```

Is there better solutions for using relative root url for installing wordpress in folder of subdomain

Comment: I'm not very sure what is it excatly what your asking. Am I right to assume that you moved your wordpress installation from the main directory to a subdirectory?

Comment: `$_SERVER` is [not really reliable](https://www.google.at/search?q=%24_SERVER+not+set&oq=%24_SERVER+not+set&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.3758j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8) for various reasons. One is, that every internal connection or every command line call won't have the data available. And that's probably the problem you're facing. What's your exact use case? Please file an [edit] and explain it.

Answer (score 1):

update the fields in general settings in wp-admin. I think it will solve your issue.
please make sure that you will not give any static path for any image